# I need to install a lockbox in a refrigerator to keep a medicine locked up. What is the best way to do that?

Tags: refrigerator

I need to install a lockbox in my refrigerator to store a medicine.

It must not be attached to anything that can be easily removed.

What's the best way to do this

Comment: Can you modify the fridge? If appearances aren't important you could drill a hike through the side and run a bolt through.

Comment: There are all kinds of lockable boxes that will fit in a fridge. https://www.amazon.com/Jssmst-GB001bl-s-Locking-Small-Steel/dp/B06XJFGH1V/ref=sr_1_16?dchild=1&keywords=Lock+Boxes&qid=1607894249&sr=8-16

Comment: What keeps the druggie from removing the entire lockbox from the fridge, hauling it off to a workshop and drilling/sawing it apart at their leisure?  Do you own the refrigerator?

Comment: "*It must not be attached to anything that can be easily removed.*"  At first reading my brain only read it must not be attached. To clarify, you want a box that can be secured  in the fridge and not be taken away from the fridge. Correct?

Comment: This is likely more about preventing the patient from accidentally overdosing themselves than keeping it safe from an abuser.  Many elderly patients loose track of time and can't recall when they have or have not taken a medication.

Comment: "must not be attached to anything that can be easily removed", I figured this was to ensure the medicine stayed refrigerated...

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with my mother who was unable to remember how often she was taking pain medications.  The solution was a locking "cash box" from a local office supply store.

The medications were in the box, which fit nicely into the refrigerator and was easily removed.  I kept one key and the other key was in a "realtor" style lock box on the front door that the visiting nurse had the combination to.  So the nurse gave her the meds in the morning and I gave them to her in the evening.

Obviously this is not highly secure but for an elderly person it was secure enough.